# How can I create a program for windows that can also be used in a website?

Tags: windows, web

I am unsure how to go about it or what languages would work together to do this. I am also not that experienced in programming.

I want this program to be able to have a Account System to register and login for users and then give them access to certain tools such as forms to fill out for reports and/or requests which can be reviewed and I also want to try to get it to work integrated into a website.

Comment: Is the user not able to use a browser on the windows machine?

Comment: No, it would be usable it is mostly to create user accounts that have access to different features such as an interactive map, a LUA scripting feature to allow users to create scripts for a game and possibly edit existing scripts under the game directories script files. Possibly add a chat that can be used through say Discord, the website, and the application.

Comment: Wow, got alot going on there. Honestly if your not a developer yourself, I would look into hiring someone. Your describing a big project that will take planning. Your not going to find that type of help here and even if you did, it would be one crazy long answer lol

Comment: Im just trying to figure out what programming language would be best suitable, but in the end I think an SQL Database tied in all together would work i'd just basically have to design a website and the application as 2 separate projects

Comment: All those questions are mainly preference? Obviously you will need to use HTML/JavaScript but for the back-end language you can pretty much pick anything. What languages do you know? Start with that question and go from there.